# Django Rest Framework, importing users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have seen importing User model in Django project as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and

```
from django.conf import settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL as User
```

What difference does these make ? *I think in both cases we import same user*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are same. Sometimes you want to use another model for Auth's project. Then you can define your model in settings.py file. like this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'membership.User'
```

and in membership app, you have a model named User

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    full_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True        
    )      

    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )

    email = models.EmailField(
        db_index=True,
        unique=True
    )
```